# Why does this weak reference test fail?

Tags: c#, weak-references

Exploring weak references, I wrote the below test to validate my understanding, but the test fails.

As far as I can tell, there are no references to the `object` that gets "newed up" in the first line (other than the one made by the `WeakReference` instance), begging the question, why does `weakRef` think it's `Target` is still alive?

What am I missing? Why does the test fail and what is still maintaining a reference to the `object`?

```
[TestMethod]
public void WeakReference()
{
    var weakRef = new WeakReference(new object(), false);
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    Assert.IsFalse(weakRef.IsAlive);
    Assert.IsNull(weakRef.Target);
}
```

Comment: @JohanP - that's not right; there is no strong reference to the object returned by `new object()`.

Comment: Debug or release build? Debugger attached? In any case, there may be better success first returning the WeakRef from its own dedicated method, with the GC done in the caller. That ensures there is no shenanigans as only the WeakRef is externally visible once the method returns. Also, isn’t there a “collect immediately” flag these days?

Comment: @JohanP - weakref doesn't count as a strong reference... that's the whole point .. it's a weak ref.

Comment: @JohanP The point of a WeakRef is that it will not cause a strong ref of the contained object. Hence the contained object _may_ be eligible for reclamation.

Comment: The test fails in both Debug and Release modes, and it makes no difference if I return the new object from a static method - the test still fails.

Answer (score 3):

I'm able to replicate your results using a normal program (not running it in mstest).

If I run the following in a non-optimized build, it prints: "Alive: true".

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        WeakReference weakRef = new WeakReference( new object(), false );

        GC.Collect( GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true );
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        // Prints true in debug, false in release.
        Console.WriteLine( "Alive: " + weakRef.IsAlive );
    }
```

If I compile with optimizations enabled, it instead works, printing "Alive: false".

Additionally, if I extract the initialization of the WeakReference to a separate method, it works regardless of the optimization:

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        WeakReference weakRef = Init();

        GC.Collect( GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true );
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        // Always prints false.
        Console.WriteLine( "Alive: " + weakRef.IsAlive );
    }

    private static WeakReference Init()
    {
        return new WeakReference( new object(), false );
    }
```

To be honest, I'm not sure of the cause. One hypothesis I had was that the temporary object was being stored in a hidden temporary variable on the stack as part of the lack of optimization. However, that doesn't make sense since the GC is able to inspect the stack to determine when the last reference to any variable has been made - the GC can collect things that are in the currently running function, so long as it's not being used anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I'm not going crazy. Optimizations does seem to fix it, but the "trick" of returning the actual objects I need from a static method doesn't work for me (this is a contrived, simplified version of the test I'm actually running). Thanks for your insights though, greatly appreciated